# Losing session values after header redirection

Tags: php, session

I'm using $_SESSION to keep my users logged in after they have logged in.

When they return to the homepage, they at first appear to be logged in, but after refreshing the page once, they are no longer logged in.

NOTE: I'm still learning PHP programming so please don't mind that most of my code is rather, noobish.

*Index.php Code:*

```
<?php
session_start();

$UserOnline = "Guest";

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $UserOnline = $_SESSION['username'];
}


echo $UserOnline;
?>
```

*Login.php Code:*

```
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($username)) {
    $InvalidLogin = "Please submit a username";
    $_SESSION['IL'] = $InvalidLogin;
    header ('Location: http://localhost/practice/index.php');
    exit;
} elseif (empty($username)) {
    $InvalidLogin = "Please submit a password";
    $_SESSION['IL'] = $InvalidLogin;
    header ('Location: http://localhost/practice/index.php');
    exit;
}


require 'required/connect.php';

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if ($password == $row['password']) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    echo "Successful Login!";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<a href='index.php'>Return to HomePage?</a>";
} else {
    $InvalidLogin = "Your info didn't match ours!";
    $_SESSION['IL'] = $InvalidLogin;
    header ('Location: http://localhost/practice/index.php');
    exit;
}


?>
```

I have tested on the login.php page if the user is in a session there, and I always get the correct return value. The issue is that after I refresh once on the Index.php page, the user is no longer in a session.

Is there something I'm forgetting, or am I not using the $_SESSION correctly? Is there another error that I simply do not know about?

Comment: Just a note that you should `exit;` after those `header()` calls checking for empty username and password. Otherwise, the script will continue to run even after those `header()` calls.

Comment: Is loginAttempt.php the same as your login.php? is that a typo or are there 3 files?

Comment: With HTTP 1.1, you don't need a full URI for the `Location` header. A simple relative path will do. Makes your code more portable

Comment: Also, change your *empty* check to `if (!isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']))`. No need to check each field individually

Comment: "To use cookie-based sessions, session_start()  must be called before outputing anything to the browser." http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php Some space before you opening php tag perhaps?

Comment: A couple of notes -First, you have significant SQL injection vulnerability now. Second, you are storing passwords in the clear in the database, which is usually bad practice.

Comment: Yes I realize, I'm just getting started in learning how to do all this.

Comment: My guess is that you haven't included all code of your `index.php` in the question, or did you?

Comment: The users are logging in fine so loginAttempt.php is never even apart of the issue. After logging in, users start a session perfectly, but after returning to the homepage, users are no longer in a session, which is confusing me.

Comment: No I didn't, most of the code is simple html and css.

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the tip that `isset()` takes multiple parameters. Didn't know that!

Comment: @jffy Are you in any way including any other PHP file?

Comment: @AngeloGeels I do use require 'required/connect.php' in the script. However, that is a simple mysql_connect function and doesn't have a session variable contained.

Comment: Ok, first things first. Enable proper error reporting. In your `php.ini` file, set `display_errors` to `On` and `error_reporting` to `E_ALL`. Also set `output_buffering` to `0` and restart your web server. My guess is that you'll start seeing some errors after this. Definitely some `E_NOTICE` *undefined indexes* and possibly a *Headers already sent*

Comment: Sounds like the session data isn't being stored/retrieved ... check your `session_set_cookie()` parameters - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php - I also suspect your `elseif` should be `empty($password)` rather than username again.

Comment: @Phil [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) is pretty clear about the need for an absolute URL: *The field value consists of a single **absolute** URI.*

Comment: @PeeHaa Hmm, Spring MVC has confused me now. When you use HTTP 1.0 compatibility, it sends a full URL (protocol scheme, hostname and all) but HTTP 1.1 mode just sends an absolute path. In any case, using a path is perfectly fine these days. There aren't any clients that will interpret it incorrectly.

Comment: No it is not perfectly fine. That's like somebody a couple of years ago saying use this IE6 specific feature which is in no spec whatsoever because in these days it works perfectly fine.

Comment: As a test - could you add a line in index.php to the effect of `echo session_id()` - I'm 99% certain it will change every time you hit refresh.

Comment: @PeeHaa Fair enough. It's good to know the risks I guess. Let's just hope that [this draft](http://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics/?include_text=1) becomes standard soon enough then.

Answer (score 1):

Put **exit;** after header('location:.....') and your problem will be solved.

Comment: @AngeloGeels Story time! http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/WellIntentioned-Destruction.aspx

Comment: Thanks guys, I never knew about "exit;", learning more and more each day!

Comment: @Phil I know about that, I don't understand how this would solve OP's problem.

Comment: Well, I'm still getting the same issue. User isn't staying logged in. Added exit; after all headers.

Comment: @AngeloGeels My guess is that `loginAttempt.php` with a `try=fail` parameter may invalidate the session. *Ok, not the case*

Comment: @Phil Even then, `login.php` isn't included on `index.php`.

Comment: @Phil I updated it with all the code from the login.php, and now updated with all php code from index.php

Comment: @AngeloGeels ,i think because without exit ,script still running in the server, and  we will have 2 session_start() running at the same time,so i think the second one override session values

Comment: At this point, I think I'll just re-use old code I have that worked. This is a new error to me and I don't know why I'm getting it.

Comment: you still have problem ?

Comment: Yes, and its just that the session isn't being stored. Honestly this is just a derp on my part.

Comment: Issue is resolved. Error was found in Index.php. Set Variable $UserOnline before the if(isset($_SESSION['username'])). Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: add this as answer and validate it :)

Comment: I have to wait 6 more hours :(

Comment: @FaceOfJock This is not the correct answer, why should he mark this as the answer?

Comment: i spoke about the answer he found

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. Error was found in Index.php. Set Variable $UserOnline before the if(isset($_SESSION['username'])). Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Could you please clarify? Looking at the code in your question (even the original code in the edit history), this answer does not make sense

Comment: I couldn't honestly tell you why it's working now. I just made a change in when I set the $UserOnline variable.